# RVM Gempath not being set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, rubygems, rvm

I recently installed RVM.  After loading my `.rvmrc` I tried `bundle install` and got the error informing me `bundler` was not installed.

After installing `bundler`, the `bundler` not installed error persisted.  After some quick digging I discovered that the RVM gem paths are not being used by rubygems.

Here is `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jhalecom/ruby/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/jhalecom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jhalecom/ruby/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jhalecom/ruby/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--remote --gen-rdoc --run-tests"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/jhalecom/ruby/gems"
     - "gempath" => []
     - "rdoc" => "--inline-source --line-numbers"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Here is `~/.bashrc`:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions


[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Here is `~/.bash_pofile`:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to clean your `~/.gemrc`, it changes the paths, best would be to rewrite it with :

```
echo gem: --gen-rdoc --run-tests > ~/.gemrc
echo rdoc: --inline-source --line-numbers >> ~/.gemrc
```

or to remove the wrong lines:

```
sed -i '/gemhome|gempath/ d;'
```