# IntelliJ IDEA 13 - Terminal error message

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, terminal

In IntelliJ IDEA 13 the new useful feature is Terminal. But all time when I open it I get have error message:

```
__rvm_fix_path_from_gem_path: command not found
rvm_is_a_shell_function: command not found
```

How to fix this issue ?

P.S. I under Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that's an issue with the terminal or the IDE itself. Judging by the error name it is probably a user configurable shell variable which gets executed every time a new shell is opened (probably part of the user home folder/configuration). If you fix the Ruby gem path issue the error will probably go away.

You could try setting up those manually by following one of the following topics:

[RVM Gempath not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204995/rvm-gempath-not-being-set)

[RVM doesn't set correct gem path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840366/rvm-doesnt-set-correct-gem-path)